# Solar Powered Water Pumping Station

Tags: pump

I'm building a system which requires water to be pumped from ground level to a height of Z, how would I determine the pump size and why? 
This is the theoretical system analysis which I need for my project report.

Comment: Why did you add the word solar to the title? The question doesn't seem to ask what is expected from reading title?  This seems like it's part of a homework problem.

Answer (score 0):

The size depends on both the flow that is desired and the head pressure, (z) in your question. You may be able to find a 1/2 hp pump that can pump 30' but only have a flow of 1 gallon per minute at 30'. If you need more flow the pump will need to be larger. The next question is the pump AC driven from a inverter or DC the Supply will need to be able to supply the pump with peak starting power or the motor will not pump efficiently and possibly over heat and or damage itself or the system.